# Validate date consistency

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I've got a kind of script in python in charge of deleting folders that are older than a given date. This is my code for doing it:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta


EXPIRATION_WEEKS=4



def delete_folder(folder: Path):
    """
    Delete the content folder.
    """
    rmtree(folder)


def check_expiration_date(folder: Path):
    expiration_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(weeks=EXPIRATION_WEEKS)
    folder_date = folder.name.split('-')[0]
    folder_date = datetime.strptime(folder_date, '%Y%m%d')
    return True if folder_date.date() < expiration_date.date() else False


def check_content_folder(folder: Path):
    """
    Check if the content folder has a concrete character
    """
    return True if '-' in folder.name else False


def delete_folders_with_expired_date(data_path: Path):
    """
    Delete the content folder.
    """

    for folder in data_path.glob('*'):
        if folder.is_dir():
            if check_content_folder(folder):
                if check_expiration_date(folder):
                    delete_folder(folder)
                    print(f"Deleted folder: {folder}")
            else:
                delete_folders_with_expired_date(folder)
```

The folder's name structure is as follows:

```
20220317-120259_.page_w_200-1.png
```

As you can see, the first part of the folder's name is the date (until '-' character).

I would like to check that the date at the beginning is consistent, i.e. that it is not a date like this:

1. 10000101
2. 28070405

Since the library in charge of formatting the string accepts this kind of date.

Comment: At first you will have to make an implementable definition of "consistent".

Comment: Of course, consistent for me are dates that make sense 20220602. A folder with a date 34520430 does not make sense so it is probably not a folder with the date at the beginning but something else.

Comment: You need 2 levels of validation. 1. A regular expression that checks for the correct number of digits and a reasonable range of years, like "must start with `20`". 2. Attempt to parse as a date using `strptime()` and reject folder names that don't parse, to reject plausible digit strings that are non- dates.

Comment: @BoarGules do you mean something like this: `True if date_str.isnumeric() and date_str.startswith('20') else False`

Comment: Yes. Though you might add `len(folder_date) == 8`. (A lot of people here would recommend a regular expression instead of a series of string tests.) But do put a `try...except` around the call to `strptime()` to avoid having the program halt on `20220229`. And, purely for the style, consider `return folder_date.date() < expiration_date.date()`. The effect is the same, but some linters would suggest it. Linters IMHO are too often opinionated and arbitrary and overfond of shibboleths, but I would concede that one.

Comment: @BoarGules great! I did everything you told me. I think now it's more pythonic and robust Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the solution I was searching, thanks to [@BoarGules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084384/boargules):

```
def validate_date(date_str: str):
    """
    Validate if is a consistent date format.
    """
    return date_str.isnumeric() and date_str.startswith('20') and len(date_str) == 8


def check_expiration_date(folder: Path):
    expiration_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(weeks=EXPIRATION_WEEKS)
    folder_date = folder.name.split('-')[0]
    if validate_date(folder_date):
        try:
            folder_date = datetime.strptime(folder_date, '%Y%m%d')
        except Exception:
            return False  # Folder name is not a valid date
        return folder_date.date() < expiration_date.date()
```